# Why supplied paramter does not match signiture of call target when object with correct interface was supplied?

Tags: typescript

My question is why object which implements some interface is not accepted by constructor which should accept the interface as a parameter.

In the example below there is `WeatherData` class which implements `Subject` interface.
There is also `CurrentConditionDisplay` class which accepts the `Subject` as a parameter in constructor.

The problem is that the instance of `WeatherData` object is not accepted by the constructor of `CurrentConditionDisplay`.
TypeScript compiler just yells

> error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not
>   match any signature of call target.

Visual Studio Code show this error:

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. (local
>   var) weatherData: WeatherStation.WeatherData

CurrentConditionDisplay.ts

```
/// <reference path="DisplayElement.ts" />
/// <reference path="Observer.ts" />
/// <reference path="Subject.ts" />
module Display {
    export class CurrentConditionDisplay implements observer.Observer, DisplayElement {
        weatherData: observer.Subject;
        temperature: number;
        humidity: number;

        CurrentConditionDisplay(weatherData: observer.Subject) {
            this.weatherData = weatherData;
            this.weatherData.registerObserver(this);
        }
        // some code here
    }
}
```

WeatherData.ts

```
/// <reference path="Subject.ts" />
/// <reference path="Observer.ts" />
module WeatherStation {
    export class WeatherData implements observer.Subject {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

MyWeatherStation.ts

```
/// <reference path="WeatherData.ts" />
/// <reference path="CurrentConditionDisplay.ts" />
class MyWeatherStation {
    MyWeatherStation() {
        var weatherData: WeatherStation.WeatherData =
                new WeatherStation.WeatherData();
        var display: Display.CurrentConditionDisplay =
                new Display.CurrentConditionDisplay(weatherData); //<--- error is here
        weatherData.setMeasurements(10,20,30);
    }
}
new MyWeatherStation();
```

And yes, I'm just having fun with Head First Design Patterns :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for declaring a constructor in TypeScript or ES6 is:

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor(your, args, here) { ... }
}
```

You've tried to write the C# version:

```
class SomeClass {
  SomeClass(your, args, here) { ... }
}
```

which just makes *this* code valid (nothing special happens when the method name is the same as the enclosing class name):

```
let x = new SomeClass();
x.SomeClass(my, arg, here);
```

You may have noticed when debugging that none of your constructor code is running ;)

Comment: Aha thank you! Sometimes the most obvious things are the most difficult to see.